# Sum columns by level in a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have my df with multi-index columns. All of my values are in float, and I want to merge values with in first level of multi-index. Please see below for detail.

```
first        bar                 baz                 foo   
second       one       two       one       two       one    
A       0.895717  0.805244  1.206412  2.565646  1.431256    
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003  0.827317  0.076467    
C       1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 

first        bar                 baz                 foo   

A       (0.895717+0.805244) (1.206412+2.565646)  1.431256    
B       (0.410835+0.813850) (0.132003+0.827317)  0.076467    
C       (1.413681+1.607920) (1.024180+0.569605)  0.875906
```

The values are actually added (I just didn't feel like doing all this :)). Bottom line is that I just want to level-up(higher level I guess) and within the index, add all the values. Please let me know a good way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a `groupby` along the first axis.

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

On older versions of pandas, this method also works:

```
df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

The `level` argument to `sum` implies grouping.

---

```
df

first  bar     baz     foo    
second one two one two one two
A        2   3   3   4  10   8
B       22  16   7   3   2  26
C        4   5   1   9   6   5

df.sum(level=0, axis=1)

first  bar  baz  foo
A        5    7   18
B       38   10   28
C        9   10   11
```

Performance wise, there's hardly any difference between the two methods outlined above (the latter is a few ticks faster).

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1, level='first')` would also work in the OP case, has index level 0 has a name.

Comment: @mins taking advantage of the named index, that's a great callout. Thanks!

Comment: A few years later and `df.sum(levels=...)` has become deprecated and will be removed from future versions. `df.groupby(levels=...).sum()` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: How can we assign sum of a single column to the **new column**?

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that `df.sum(level, axis)` will only work if you set your columns to the multi-index. Example,

```
D = {'one': range(6), 
     'two': range(1,7), 
     'CAT1': 'A A A A A A'.split(), 
     'CAT2': 'B B B C C C'.split(), 
     'CAT3': 'D D E E F F'.split()}

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
df = df.set_index('CAT1 CAT2 CAT3'.split())
df
                one  two
CAT1 CAT2 CAT3          
A    B    D       0    1
          D       1    2
          E       2    3
     C    E       3    4
          F       4    5
          F       5    6
```

If your data is in this form, you will have to use `df.groupby(level=n).sum(axis=1)`

```
df.groupby(level = 0).sum(axis=1)

      one  two
CAT1          
A      15   21

df.groupby(level = 1).sum(axis=1)

      one  two
CAT2          
B       3    6
C      12   15

df.groupby(level = 2).sum(axis=1)

      one  two
CAT3          
D       1    3
E       5    7
F       9   11
```

If you try skipping the `groupby`,

```
df.sum(level = 1, axis=1)

ValueError: level > 0 or level < -1 only valid with  MultiIndex
```

Which is an interesting error since,

```
df.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A'], [u'B', u'C'], [u'D', u'E', u'F']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]],
           names=[u'CAT1', u'CAT2', u'CAT3'])
```