# Summing or groupby at different levels with MultiIndex columns?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where, to avoid tuple column names, I intentionally used blank levels:

```
>>> df
      user1 user2 count
                   0      1             2
                   a      a      b      a 
    0  2     6     0      1      0      0
    1  4     6     0      0      0      3
    2  21    76    2      0      1      0
    3  5     18    0      0      0      0
```

Note that `user1` and `user2` are at the same level as `count` (side effect of merging).

I want to have a new column (maybe under `count`?) that takes the sum, of, say, all `1` and `2` (**`0` not included!**) for every letter. That would mean:

```
>>> df
      user1 user2 count
                   0      1             2       sum_1_2
                   a      a      b      a       a        b
    0  2     6     0      1      0      0       1+0      0
    1  4     6     0      0      0      3       0        0+3
    2  21    76    2      0      1      0       0        0
    3  5     18    0      0      0      0       0        0
```

I've tried `df.groupby(level=[0,2]).sum()` based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272452/sum-columns-by-level-in-a-multi-index-dataframe) but they don't give me the results I want (they include the `0` column in the sum as well and they also sum `user1` and `user2`).

GENERATOR CODE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,4,21,21],'user2':[6,6,76,76],'param1':[1,2,0,1],'param2':['a','a','a','b'],'count':[1,3,2,1]}, columns=['user1','user2','param1','param2','count'])
df = df.set_index(['user1','user2','param1','param2'])
df = df.unstack([2,3]).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,5,21],'user2':[6,18,76]})
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, [''],['']])
final_df = df2.merge(df, on=['user1','user2'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) for filter only `1,2`, then `sum` and add levels for same levels like original `DataFrame` for possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df3 = final_df.loc[:, idx[:, [1,2],:]].sum(level=2, axis=1)
df3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['count'], ['sum_1_2'], df3.columns])
print (df3)
    count     
  sum_1_2     
        a    b
0     1.0  0.0
1     0.0  0.0
2     0.0  1.0
3     3.0  0.0

df = pd.concat([final_df, df3], axis=1)
print (df)
  user1 user2 count                            
                  0    1         2 sum_1_2     
                  a    a    b    a       a    b
0     2     6   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0     1.0  0.0
1     5    18   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0  0.0
2    21    76   2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0     0.0  1.0
3     4     6   0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0     3.0  0.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (final_df.loc[:, idx[:, [1,2],:]])
  count          
      1         2
      a    b    a
0   1.0  0.0  0.0
1   0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  1.0  0.0
3   0.0  0.0  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! MultiIndex columns is new to me and I find it difficult to work with. One more question: with the `concat` operation, is it guaranteed that the order of the indices is preserved?

Comment: @irene - I test it by `df3 = df3.sort_index(axis=1, level=2, ascending=False)` and if check final `df` it preserve ordering.

Comment: I tried that test and the `sort_index` only on the column indices (axis=1). I was thinking about the row indices though. Since the two dataframes have to be concatenated, then the row indices have to be consistent.

Comment: @irene - Yes, there is no reason for change ordering ;)