# Adding a column to a multiindex summing a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to add another column that contains the total sum of the salary column for each native-country and insert it for each native-country & salary combo.

This is what I've tried

```
a = df.groupby(['native-country','salary'])[['salary']].count()
a.columns = ['number']
a['total'] = a.sum(level=0, axis=0)
```

Which returns

```
                       number  total
native-country salary               
?              <=50K      437    NaN
               >50K       146    NaN
Cambodia       <=50K       12    NaN
               >50K         7    NaN
Canada         <=50K       82    NaN
...                       ...    ...
United-States  >50K      7171    NaN
Vietnam        <=50K       62    NaN
               >50K         5    NaN
Yugoslavia     <=50K       10    NaN
               >50K         6    NaN

[82 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: your output doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to sum the salary column? You can't add strings together like `>50K `and `<=50K`

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: @noah for example I'm trying to get the sum of 12 & 7 for Cambodia. I would like the new column to have 19 for both the >50k and the <=50k.

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0)['Number'].sum()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum columns by level in a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272452/sum-columns-by-level-in-a-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I think this is what you are looking for. But your question is still unclear so maybe I am wrong in my assumption.

```
a['total'] = a.groupby(level=0)["Number].sum()
```

Comment: Native country is on the index. You can use level=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = df.groupby(['native-country','salary'])[['salary']].count()
a.join(a.sum(level=0).rename(columns={'salary':'Total'}))
```

Here is a MVCE:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df_tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

df_out = df_tips.groupby(['sex','smoker'])[['tip']].sum()
df_out.join(df_out.sum(level=0).rename(columns={'tip':'total'}))
```

Output:

```
                  tip   total
sex    smoker                
Male   Yes     183.07  485.07
       No      302.00  485.07
Female Yes      96.74  246.51
       No      149.77  246.51
```